# PhoneGap touch events only firing once device has been rotated

Tags: javascript, cordova, touch

Using PhoneGap build with PG 2.2.0 and testing on my Galaxy S2 with Android 4.0.4

I already found [touch events not working in android phonegap webview (or even built-in browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453230/touch-events-not-working-in-android-phonegap-webview-or-even-built-in-browser) and [Phonegap on Galaxy S3 ignores touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862347/phonegap-on-galaxy-s3-ignores-touch-events) and [WebView in ICS touch events not being fired properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390902/webview-in-ics-touch-events-not-being-fired-properly) but I'm not sure if they describe the exact same problem.

I'm using Tap.js and iScroll. Neither of them works (I can't scroll or use my app menu) until I rotate the device at least once. I can rotate it back to where I started and it still works. It seems like the first rotation/orientationchange triggers some kind of refresh but I have no clue how I'm supposed to handle this.

Maybe someone with the same symptoms was able to resolve this. Thanks.

Edit: I disabled all JS and put this code inside `deviceready`

```
document.getElementById('app').addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
    alert('touchstart #app');
}, false);
```

And I only get the `alert` after at least one `orientationchange`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I took my app apart and created a test case, I found the following: Adding `position:relative;` to `html` or `body` in combination with `overflow:hidden;` seems to have caused the issue.

To fully resolve my issue, I took the following steps:

- Made html and body `static` again
- Removed `overflow:hidden;` from html and body
- Instead applied both to `#app` (my wrapper div)
- Listen to `touchstart touchmove touchend` on `document` level and `preventDefault`

Update 12th Jun 2013, another important find:

- **If you call preventDefault for `touchstart`, then `touchmove` will not fire**